# What causes my laptop to wake up randomly?

Tags: kubuntu, suspend, kde, wakeup

My `kubuntu` laptop very often (always?) wakes up when I disconnect it from its dock (a USB-C connector to a dock with external monitor, network cable and not much else). It also seems to wake up at other times but I haven't been able to reproduce. I first thought it was `kalarm` causing the wakeups (I can hear the alarm messages), but the wake option is disabled and I haven't been able to reproduce.
And after it woke up in my bag, it won't go back to sleep, so it's boiling hot and it drains the battery. If I put it to sleep on the desk and leave it there, it stays suspended.

It's a very recent model, up to date BIOS, with a fresh kubuntu install:

```
$ inxi -b
System:    Host: xxxx01234x Kernel: 5.11.0-31-generic x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: KDE Plasma 5.21.4 
        Distro: Ubuntu 21.04 (Hirsute Hippo) 
Machine:   Type: Laptop System: Dell product: Latitude 7420 v: N/A serial: <superuser required> 
        Mobo: Dell model: 07MHG4 v: A00 serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Dell v: 1.7.1 date: 06/08/2021 
Battery:   ID-1: BAT0 charge: 61.9 Wh condition: 61.9/61.9 Wh (100%) 
CPU:       Info: Quad Core 11th Gen Intel Core i7-1185G7 [MT MCP] speed: 831 MHz min/max: 400/4800 MHz 
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel TigerLake GT2 [Iris Xe Graphics] driver: i915 v: kernel 
        Device-2: Sunplus Innovation Integrated_Webcam_FHD type: USB driver: uvcvideo 
        Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.11 driver: loaded: modesetting unloaded: fbdev,vesa resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz 
        OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel Xe Graphics (TGL GT2) v: 4.6 Mesa 21.0.3 
Network:   Device-1: Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX201 driver: iwlwifi 
Drives:    Local Storage: total: 953.87 GiB used: 617.4 GiB (64.7%) 
Info:      Processes: 318 Uptime: 1h 03m Memory: 15.36 GiB used: 4.58 GiB (29.8%) Shell: Bash inxi: 3.3.01
```

From the syslog I can't identify what caused the wakeup:

```
$ sort /proc/acpi/wakeup | grep -v disabled
Device  S-state   Status   Sysfs node
AWAC      S4    *enabled   platform:ACPI000E:00
LID0      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0D:00
PBTN      S3    *enabled   platform:PNP0C0C:00
PEG0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:06.0
RP07      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:1c.0
TDM0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.2
TRP0      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.0
TRP1      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:07.1
TXHC      S4    *enabled   pci:0000:00:0d.0
XHCI      S0    *enabled   pci:0000:00:14.0


$ cat /var/log/syslog         # (with some cleanup)
...
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Reached target Sleep.
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Starting Suspend...
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Stopping Atop advanced performance monitor...
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: atop.service: Succeeded.
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Stopped Atop advanced performance monitor.
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x systemd-sleep[54424]: Suspending system...
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x kernel: PM: suspend entry (s2idle)
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x kernel: Filesystems sync: 0.005 seconds
Aug 29 20:48:30 xxxx01234x PackageKit: get-updates transaction /367_cadbbdec from uid 10705 finished with success after 265ms
```

And then it wakes up a few seconds later:

```
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: Freezing user space processes ... (elapsed 0.002 seconds) done.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: OOM killer disabled.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: Freezing remaining freezable tasks ... (elapsed 0.000 seconds) done.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: printk: Suspending console(s) (use no_console_suspend to debug)
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt blocked
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: ACPI: EC: interrupt unblocked
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: ACPI Error: Thread 2516336000 cannot release Mutex [ECMX] acquired by thread 2266192960 (20201113/exmutex-378)
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: No Local Variables are initialized for Method [_Q66]
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: No Arguments are initialized for method [_Q66]
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PC00.LPCB.ECDV._Q66 due to previous error (AE_AML_NOT_OWNER) (20201113/psparse-529)
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: i915 0000:00:02.0: [drm] *ERROR* failed to enable link training
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: OOM killer enabled.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: Restarting tasks ... done.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: usb 3-2: USB disconnect, device number 4
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: usb 3-2.3: USB disconnect, device number 5
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: mei_hdcp 0000:00:16.0-b638ab7e-94e2-4ea2-a552-d1c54b627f04: bound 0000:00:02.0 (ops i915_hdcp_component_ops [i915])
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: usb 2-2: USB disconnect, device number 2
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x org.kde.KScreen[1839]: kscreen.xcb.helper: RRNotify_OutputProperty (ignored)
...
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x org.kde.KScreen[1839]: kscreen.xrandr: Output 71 : connected = false , enabled = true
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Condition check resulted in Daily apt download activities being skipped.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Starting Message of the Day...
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: motd-news.service: Succeeded.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Finished Message of the Day.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: thermal thermal_zone6: failed to read out thermal zone (-61)
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 27
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd-sleep[54424]: System resumed.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x bluetoothd[893]: Controller resume with wake event 0x0
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: PM: suspend exit
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Starting Atop advanced performance monitor...
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Started Atop advanced performance monitor.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: systemd-suspend.service: Succeeded.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Finished Suspend.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Stopped target Sleep.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Reached target Suspend.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x systemd[1]: Stopped target Suspend.
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x ModemManager[1070]: <info>  [sleep-monitor] system is resuming
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x NetworkManager[896]: <info>  manager: sleep: wake requested (sleeping: yes  enabled: yes)
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x NetworkManager[896]: <info>  device (wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 28
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: usb 3-2.4: USB disconnect, device number 6
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x acpid: input device has been disconnected, fd 29
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x kernel: usb 3-2.5: USB disconnect, device number 7
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x NetworkManager[896]: <info>  device (p2p-dev-wlp0s20f3): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
...
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x NetworkManager[896]: <warn>  sup-iface[4da570032317dfb3,2,wlp0s20f3]: call-p2p-cancel: failed with P2P cancel failed
Aug 29 20:48:49 xxxx01234x org.kde.KScreen[1839]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
...
Aug 29 20:48:52 xxxx01234x org.kde.KScreen[1839]: kscreen.xrandr: Emitting configChanged()
Aug 29 20:48:53 xxxx01234x wpa_supplicant[960]: wlp0s20f3: CTRL-EVENT-REGDOM-CHANGE init=DRIVER type=COUNTRY alpha2=FR
Aug 29 20:48:53 xxxx01234x NetworkManager[896]: <info>  policy: auto-activating connection 'DargaudWifiW' (5992f5f3-2312-4cc9-9bd7-07adbf68c46d)
...
```

Comment: Could there be an option in the BIOS that's causing it to wake up?  Probably you can look through the BIOS menus to remove that as a possibility first?

Comment: No, I forgot to mention it but I looked around the BIOS and turned off every 'Wake on...' option

Comment: In my case, my laptop wakes up when I hit a key.  Of course, I think you'd notice if there was a sticky key...  But off the top of my head that's another potential cause to consider.  Or maybe something brushed against the touchpad?  Of course, you can disprove either easily by hitting a key or touching the mouse area to see if that wakes up your computer...

Comment: I tried changing the order I do things: turn external monitor off, unplug monitor/power, close lid -> seems to stay off. Close lid, unplug monitor/power -> wakes back up.

Comment: Is there a way in KDE to disable any waking except the ON/OFF button ?

Comment: I've found my Ubuntu wakes up on notifications.

Answer (score 0):

What solved for me was to enable two checkboxes in the bios like this:
[image: https://pasteboard.co/teVWw8wvkMWp.png]

Comment: I will check if I have the same options on next reboot, but it would be nice to have a breakdown on _what_ those options actually do.